# Using SQL script in Toad, how do I suppress the echo of the SQL statements

Tags: oracle, scripting, toad

I'm using a script (`Toad`, `Oracle`) so that I can use variables and enter two values that get repeated in multiple SQL statements.

That's working great, but the SQL statements echo into the console output.

I don't expect grid output, but I would like the SQL statement echo to be suppressed 
(I'm glad it's an option, but once things are working it's just in the way).

Is there a way to get rid of that?

Comment: I think you probably need to add `set echo off` at the top of the script you're running.

Comment: Good idea, but it doesn't do what I'm after

Comment: Please edit your question to show an example of your script, what it’s actually doing, and what you want it to do; we might stand a better chance of being able to help you then.